# Can HDF5 perform "value mapping"?

Tags: hdf5

If I have a 32^3 array of 64 bit integers, but it contains only a dozen different values, can you tell HDF5 to use an "internal mapping" to save memory and/or disk space? What I mean is that the array would be access normally with 64 bit ints, but each value would internally be stored as a byte (?) index into a table of 64 bit ints, potentially saving about 7/8 of the memory and/or disk space. If this is possible, does it actually saves memory, disk space or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that HDF5 provides this functionality right out of the box, but there is no reason why you couldn't implement routines to write your data to an HDF5 file and read it back again in the way that you seem to want.  I suppose you could write your look-up table and your array into different datasets.

It's possible, but not something I have any evidence to indicate, that HDF's compression facility would sufficiently compress your integer dataset that you could save a useful amount of space.

Then again, for the HDF5 files I work with (10s of GBs) I wouldn't bother to try to devise my own encoding scheme to save such modest amounts of space as a 32768 element array of 64 bit numbers might be able to dispense with.  Sure, you could transform a dataset of 2097152 bits into one of 131072 but disk space (even RAM) just isn't that tight these days.

I'm beginning to form the impression that you are trying to use HDF5 on, perhaps, a smartphone :-)

Comment: Well, it's not so much disk space itself that maters, but rather RAM and "bandwidth" between the client and server. If the file are compressed on the server, then it saves bandwidth, but you can't access data that is compressed without decompressing it first, so that doesn't save RAM. Table-mapping saves both RAM and bandwidth, but I suppose it doesn't seem difficult for me to perform the mapping manually..